# HttpClient POST request to https

Tags: post, https, windows-8, httpclient

I'm working on a WinRT app that does login to a webpage and get some data. The problem is that I'm getting a "HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request" message. Here is the code:

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://miyoigo-b.yoigo.com/selfcare/login");
HttpContent msg = new StringContent("account[cli]=" + number + "&password=" + pass);
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.UseCookies = true;
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpClient req = new HttpClient(handler);
req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "miyoigo-b.yoigo.com");
req.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
HttpResponseMessage response = await req.PostAsync(url, msg);
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've been trying a lot of thing I found over the internet, even disabling my firewall, but nothing worked. I'm porting this from a Windows Phone app and it did work with this:

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://miyoigo-b.yoigo.com/selfcare/login");
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.Headers["Host"] = "miyoigo-b.yoigo.com";
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(WriteCallback), req);
```

And afterwards, in the Callback I created a Stream and wrote the credentials.

Any idea?? I know that the problem is only with this webpage, maybe I'm forgetting to send something or the format of the POST content is not correct...

Thanks

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` with more details?

Comment: I'm seeing an error indicating it can't establish a SSL/TLS secure channel - is that what you're getting?

Comment: Did you add the required capabilities in the manifest of you app?

Comment: I added "Home or Work Networking" and "Internet (Client & Server)" but I'm still with the same problem

Comment: If you have problem with establishing SSL/TLS it means that your machine doesn't trust certificate for that site. What happens if you try to access that address from browser?

Comment: I've tried with Firefox, Chrome and IE, and they all work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problema was that Win8 Metro Apps only accepts SSL3.1 and this webpage was using SSL3.0. The solution was using the new version of the webpage.

Thank you all